# How many Ki points can a monk spend per turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk

Flurry of Blows, Patient Defense, and Step of the Wind each cost 1 Ki point to use and use a bonus action. Does that mean I can only use 1 per turn, since I can only take 1 bonus action per turn?

At the same time it feels like Ki points are kind of like spell slots, and maybe if I get the ability to spend more Ki I can use more of these abilities in a turn.

Can anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get the chance. I cleaned up your question a bit to keep it focused, but if you don't like any of the changes I made you can use [edit] button just below the question's tags to fix it up however you'd like.

Answer (score 27):

### One bonus action is a hard limit

No matter how many Ki you might want to spend, you can never take more than one bonus action on your turn.

#### Actions aren't consumable points, they're limits

Whenever you're looking at rules talking about types of actions, think of them less as “spending” actions and more as counting them. As you do things on your turn, the number of Actions, Bonus Actions, and Reactions are limited: when the things you've done reach your limit in any action type, you can't do any more things that count as that action type.

You don't “spend” action types so much as you count up what you've done using abilities you have, until you hit the limits. I know this seems like a silly distinction, but it actually makes it easier to read the rules, since they're written with this “action limit” idea in mind.

#### Ki *are* consumable points

In contrast to actions, Ki *are* something you “spend”.

You can spend more Ki points during your turn on other abilities, but *using* the abilities will still be constrained by the normal limits on taking actions. Think of spending Ki as allowing you to use an ability at all, as powering the action. You still spend any needed actions to *actually* use the ability.

For example, you could spend 1 Ki to power Step of the Wind and another 4 Ki to power Empty Body, but actually using those abilities would still count as taking a bonus action to Disengage and an action to turn invisible. Having taken both an action and a bonus action, you'd have hit your 1-per-turn limits for those and you can't do anything else on your turn that counts as an action or bonus action.

Comment: I  upvoted this one, since it seems to answer the asked question the best, but I think it's worth mentioning other ways of spending Ki on things that aren't bonus actions. You can spend Ki on those and on bonus actions separately.

Comment: @Ethan I went to add that, but to make sense it ended up needing a fuller explanation of action economy and its conceptual underpinnings, so it got a *bit* longer… How well does that cover what you felt was missing?

Comment: That looks good to me!

Answer (score 14):

### You can spend an unlimited number provided you can take the associated actions.

Certain monk abilities (Way of The Shadow's Shadow Arts, Way of the Open Hand's Quivering Palm and others) spend multiple Ki points on one ability, and use other action types than the bonus action. There is nothing preventing you from spending Ki points in multiple ways per turn, provided you can take the actions that spend them.

Answer (score 8):

As others have stated:

- You can spend as many Ki points in 1 turn as you like providing you have an action, bonus action, or reaction available to expend a Ki point.
- Spending KP does not affect the number of actions, bonus actions, reactions, etc you get.

Eg: I am determined to Stun an enemy using Stunning Strike. On my character's turn:

1. Make my first attack
2. Spend 1kp to force the target to save. He saves and is not stunned
3. Spend 1kp to use Flurry of Blows.
4. Make my first FoB attack. Spend 1kp to attempt SS again. Target saves.
5. Make second FoB attack. Spend 3kp to initiate Quivering Palm. Spend 1kp for SS. Target saves.
6. Make second standard attack. Spend 1kp for SS. Target finally fails save and is stunned.

Total KP spent: 8

Total actions used: 1 regular and 1 bonus

Additionally, on another character's turn I can still spend 1kp to Deflect Missile on a reaction.

Comment: Great example, and good summary of the other answers.  Welcome to RPG.SE. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to get a feel for this Q&A sites basic framework.  (You'll get badges for so doing, which is nice).  This is a nice first answer, I only added the edit to preface / introduce the action economy point that you do cover in the answer.  Please review the edit and edit again  if you feel it's necessary. Glad to have you join us, and we hope you'll participate more in the future.

Comment: Incidentally, you can actually use Deflect Missile on your own turn as well provided a missile is fired at you via a triggered trap or a readied action. This would allow you to use your reaction and spend a ki point throwing the missile while also using everything you have listed above as well.

Answer (score 4):

### You only get one Bonus Action

The [SRD](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/combat/theOrderofCombat.htm#bonusActivities) states: *"You can take only one bonus action on your turn, so you must choose which bonus action to use when you have more than one available."*

You are allowed to spend more than one Ki point per turn (maybe for Stunning Strike or something similar), but the above limit applies regardless of how many you spend.

Answer (score 3):

## Ki point usage is determined by Monk subclass ability options

The most Ki Points that can be spent is 6. This is for the Way of the Four Elements Monk (PHB, 80) that can invest 6 Ki points to cast certain spells or engage their Elemental Discipline.

### Action Economy

Many of the monk ki point options are engaged using a Bonus Action. You still only get one bonus action/turn, so that limits the options as you can't stack multiple Monk abilities that require a Bonus Action.

Comment: There is one that is more than that.  The Empty Body power at 18th level allows the spending of 8 Ki points to astrally project the monk.

Answer (score 1):

You may spend as many Ki points as you have actions, bonus actions, or reactions for. You may also spend as many Ki points for as many other Ki features that require Ki points that you meet all other prerequisites for, granted that you don't exceed your Ki point maximum.